# getting id of a input using id from another element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hidden

I'm trying to get the id of an input using jquery. What I do is I get the id of a button I click, then I concatenate the string to get the id of the element I want to have. But when I get the var picloc to show, it says undefined. How do I get the id of the hidden input?

```
$('.photo-frame').click(function (){
var id = this.id;
var picloc = $('#'+id+'_location').val();
$('#picture-selected').html(id);

});

<span class="photo-frame"  id="<?php echo $filetitle2;?>">
</span>
<input id="<?php echo $filetitle2;?>_location" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hidden element is just the next of span in DOM then You can use following script.

```
$('.photo-frame').click(function (){
var hidden_element = $(this).next('input:hidden').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.photo-frame').click(function (){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var picloc = $('#'+id+'_location').val();
$('#picture-selected').html(id);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = this.id;
```

has some problems.

`this` refers to the document's itself. You should surround it with a `$()` in order to point the clicked element. And I do not know if `[object].id` is usable.

Change the line as the following.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var currentId = $('#element').attr('id');
```

This will only work provided that you have a valid jQuery object `$(this)`, eg:

```
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to use the above block of codes inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` or the page itself.